# SP 2103 Differential Backup runs without Full

Tags: backup

I'm at the stage of creating backup schedule for our brand-new Sharepoint site. Copy-pasted some scripts, made Windows Task Schedule, everything is fine. Now: 
I ran Full backup then few differentials, deleted backup folder (together with spbrtoc.xml).

Whenever I'm trying to run differential (doesn't matter from command line or fron Task Scheduler) it JUST RUNS, recreating spbrtoc.xml and assuming that FullBackup folder is still there.

The whole point of exercise was to test failure message from backupscript - but there's no failure (well, untill I try to restore from no existing Full).

What I'm doing wrong? Why it doesn't fail?

Comment: can you share the script which having the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried this scenario my self  - but I suspect the issue lies in the the bitflags for files and SQL server.  The file system or SQL does not know or care that you deleted the files, what they know is they have run a Full backup and some Diffs, and their flags are set accordingly.

If you want to capture a backup failure you can do so in the scheduled job by updating your script with an exit code, this will track failures in the scheduled task history. I also believe the actual backup failure is logged in the event logs so you could trigger an event on it as well.